# Import settings.py Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I've got a testmultiple folder which contains an `__init__.py` file, pipelines, settings, and a `core.py` file which I use to launch several spiders located in a subfolder (spiders). I noticed that I had to import settings to use pipeline with `CrawlerProcess`. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.settings import Settings
import settings as my_settings
from spiders.DemoSpider import DemoSpider
from spiders.DemoSpider2 import DemoSpider2


crawler_settings = Settings()
crawler_settings.setmodule(my_settings)
process = CrawlerProcess(settings=crawler_settings)

process.crawl(DemoSpider)
process.crawl(DemoSpider2)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

But it fails on the 4th line. With this try I have :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testmultiple'
```

When I try :

```
from testmultiple.settings import settings as my_settings
```

I have same error, and with this line as well:

```
from testmultiple import settings as my_settings
```

How to import `settings.py` ?

Comment: Is this `testmuptipe`  module of yours? If yes have you installed it?

Comment: post your folder structure

Comment: Ok with your questions I realized that I didn't read the doc carrefully enough ! I had to replace the wrong line by this one :
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
and now it's fine.... sorry ^^

Comment: Please post it as answer